# Reduce left joins complexity

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi Im actually working with a query made in oracle 11g and I make a query very big. Is there a way to reduce the left joins Im making?

I don´t know how to reduce them and actually, I think I use every part of the code, can you give me advices of how to reduce the code a little?

```
SELECT FOLIO_EXP,
       FOLIO,
       DOC,
       REFERENCIA,
       TARJETA,
       CUENTA,
       NOMBRE,
       IMPORTE,
       IMP_REC,
       IMP_REPRE,
       IMP_QUEB,
       FECHA_PAGO,
       MCC,
       COMERCIO,
       PCC,
       FECHA_COM,
       ADQUIRENTE,
       ESTADO,
       "TIPO DE FRAUDE",
       F_FRAUDE,
       F_RECLAMO,
       F_REEMBOLSO,
       DICAMINO
FROM
  (SELECT E.FOLIO_EXP,
          A.FOLIO,
          'D' AS DOC,
          A.REFERENCIA,
          A.TARJETA,
          A.ACCT_NUM AS CUENTA,
          B.NOMBRE_TH AS NOMBRE,
          TO_CHAR(A.MONTO,'999,999.99') IMPORTE,
          D.IMP_REC,
          F.IMP_REPRE,
          DECODE((A.MONTO -D.IMP_REC),NULL,A.MONTO,(A.MONTO -D.IMP_REC)) AS IMP_QUEB,
          D.FECHA_PAGO,
          A.SIC_CDE AS MCC,
          A.COMERCIO,
          C.PCC,
          C.FECHA_COM,
          C.ADQUIRENTE,
          C.ESTADO,
          'INTERNET' AS "TIPO DE FRAUDE",
          A.FECHA_TRANS AS F_FRAUDE,
          A.FECHA_RECLAMO AS F_RECLAMO,
          A.FECHA_BONIFICACION AS F_REEMBOLSO,
          A.USUARIO AS DICAMINO
   FROM OPPF.T00EMISOR A

   LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT A.FECHA,
             A.TARJETA,
             C.PCC,
             C.FECHA_COM,
             C.ADQUIRENTE,
             C.ESTADO
      FROM
        (SELECT TARJETA,
                MAX(FECHA_INFO) FECHA
         FROM OPPF.T00_PCC
         GROUP BY TARJETA) A
      LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT FECHA_INFO,
                TARJETA,
                PCC,
                FECHA_COM,
                ADQUIRENTE,
                ESTADO
         FROM OPPF.T00_PCC)C ON(A.TARJETA = C.TARJETA
                                AND A.FECHA = C.FECHA_INFO)) C ON(TO_CHAR(C.TARJETA) = TO_CHAR(A.TARJETA))

   LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT MAX(SE_REVISO) SE_REVISO,
             NOMBRE_TH,
             TARJETA
      FROM OPPF.T00CASOSRESUELTOS
      GROUP BY TARJETA,
               NOMBRE_TH) B ON(SUBSTR(A.TARJETA,1,16) = SUBSTR(B.TARJETA,1,16)
                               AND A.FECHA_BONIFICACION = B.SE_REVISO)
   LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT MAX(FECHA_PAGO) FECHA_PAGO,
             TARJETA,
             REFERENCIA,
             COUNT(REFERENCIA) N,
             SUM(MONTO_LIQ) AS IMP_REC--, FECHA_TRXS

      FROM OPPF.T00_CC_RECUP
      GROUP BY TARJETA,
               REFERENCIA,
               FECHA_TRXS) D ON(TO_CHAR(D.TARJETA) = TO_CHAR(A.TARJETA)
                                AND D.REFERENCIA = A.REFERENCIA)
   LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT TARJETA,
             COUNT(TARJETA) TRANS,
             COUNT(REFERENCIA) NR,
             REFERENCIA,
             SUM(IMPORTE) IMP_REPRE
      FROM OPPF.T00_REPRESENTACIONES
      GROUP BY TARJETA,
               REFERENCIA) F ON(A.TARJETA = F.TARJETA
                                AND LPAD(TO_CHAR(A.REFERENCIA),23,'0') = LPAD(TO_CHAR(F.REFERENCIA),23,'0'))
   LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT MIN(FOLIO) FOLIO_EXP,
             TARJETA,
             FECHA_BONIFICACION
      FROM OPPF.T00EMISOR --WHERE FECHA_BONIFICACION BETWEEN '02/09/2015' AND '31/12/2015'

      GROUP BY FECHA_BONIFICACION,
               TARJETA
      ORDER BY FECHA_BONIFICACION,
               TARJETA,
               FOLIO_EXP) E ON(E.TARJETA = A.TARJETA
                               AND E.FECHA_BONIFICACION = A.FECHA_BONIFICACION)
   WHERE A.ENTRY_MODE IN ('   ',
                          '1',
                          '01',
                          '001',
                          '0',
                          '00',
                          '012',
                          '010',
                          '12',
                          '10',
                          '11',
                          '011'))
WHERE F_REEMBOLSO = '04/07/2017'

ORDER BY FOLIO,
         REFERENCIA
```

Is it recommended to use indexes and place this in a sp? The main question is how to reduce the left joins part.

Thanks

Comment: I think it would help someone if you explained what you are actually trying to achieve, especially given your table names are not obvious, at least not to English-speaking readers. Post some some data, the results you are getting, and explain what you are actually trying to achieve. This will make it much easier for someone to read your code and assist you.

Comment: You say the query was made in Oracle 11g.  Are you still running on that version or do you have 12c now?

Comment: You have two repeat table references, both of which can be changed to use analytic/OLAP queries.  For the rest of it, though, without better knowledge of your dataset it's hard to tell what else can be eliminated.  I suspect that most of these should be regular `INNER JOIN`s, and that some of the subselects can be removed (`OPPF.T00CASOSRESUELTOS`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As elementary (not advanced) approaches, I'd suggest you to:

1. Take out each subquery to a separated **VIEW** (while they don't have any parameters).
2. Or else - not sure if this will be useful to you - reorder your query and declare an alias for each subquery in the **WITH** clause:

   ```
   WITH a AS 
   (SELECT ... FROM...),
   b AS 
   (SELECT ... FROM...),
   c AS 
   (SELECT ... FROM...)
   SELECT ... 
   FROM a 
   LEFT JOIN b ... 
   LEFT JOIN c
   ```

   https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause
3. Or else, consider coding the same query logic in a client language. Such huge queries usually turn out a nightmare to be maintained.

Comment: 1) Possibly of limited utility, as some are very specific.  2) Doesn't really _reduce_ the complexity, just moves it into another location.  3) Except for some **very** specific circumstances, not a great idea: If the query returns results of any real size, programmatic joins are going to take more resources than in the DB, and increases the complexity of the system, too (since now you have to account for things like DB connection failure).  Oh, and this isn't a huge query - only somewhat middling-to-large-ish.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Oh, well. Then, maintaining such a middle-to-large query will only turn out a _headache_. :-)

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, using WITH clauses (with appropriately meaningful names - as opposed to A,B,C as used by the OP) generally does improve the *perceived* complexity, and makes clearer the logic of the main query which relates and assembles the subqueries. I agree with your other points however - this is not a particularly large query, and it would be unthinkable to move it to the client-side.

Comment: Thanks I will use the with statement

Comment: @Steve - no, I agree, and I'd possibly move some things into CTEs as well (naming isn't really an issue, since you could of course provide good names  for a subquery too).