# distinct or group by in a query

Tags: oracle, group-by, distinct

I have a query for retrieving the data for some tables in a oracle database.

What I need at the end is get all the data that is not duplicated, to achieve this I need all the records that does not have the same  FOLIO, TARJETA, CUENTA, and IMPORTE.
So for this I tried to use Distinct and Group by but I don't know where/how should it be used in the script AND if its possible where could it be more efficent.

I tried to place GROUP BY with the values before ORDER BY but it says "not a GROUP BY expression". I don't want to modify the query just remove the duplicates with those arguments duplicated (FOLIO, TARJETA, CUENTA, and IMPORTE).

```
SELECT FOLIO_EXP,
       FOLIO,
       DOC,
       REFERENCIA,
       TARJETA,
       CUENTA,
       NOMBRE,
       IMPORTE,
       IMP_REC,
       IMP_REPRE,
       IMP_QUEB,
       FECHA_PAGO,
       MCC,
       COMERCIO,
       PCC,
       FECHA_COM,
       ADQUIRENTE,
       ESTADO,
       "TIPO DE FRAUDE",
       F_FRAUDE,
       F_RECLAMO,
       F_REEMBOLSO,
       DICAMINO
FROM
  (SELECT E.FOLIO_EXP,
          A.FOLIO,
          'D' AS DOC,
          A.REFERENCIA,
          A.TARJETA,
          A.ACCT_NUM AS CUENTA,
          B.NOMBRE_TH AS NOMBRE,
          TO_CHAR(A.MONTO,'999,999.99') IMPORTE,
          D.IMP_REC,
          F.IMP_REPRE,
          DECODE((A.MONTO -D.IMP_REC),NULL,A.MONTO,(A.MONTO -D.IMP_REC)) AS IMP_QUEB,
          D.FECHA_PAGO,
          A.SIC_CDE AS MCC,
          A.COMERCIO,
          C.PCC,
          C.FECHA_COM,
          C.ADQUIRENTE,
          C.ESTADO,
          'INTERNET' AS "TIPO DE FRAUDE",
          A.FECHA_TRANS AS F_FRAUDE,
          A.FECHA_RECLAMO AS F_RECLAMO,
          A.FECHA_BONIFICACION AS F_REEMBOLSO,
          A.USUARIO AS DICAMINO
   FROM OPPF.T00EMISOR A

   LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT A.FECHA,
             A.TARJETA,
             C.PCC,
             C.FECHA_COM,
             C.ADQUIRENTE,
             C.ESTADO
      FROM
        (SELECT TARJETA,
                MAX(FECHA_INFO) FECHA
         FROM OPPF.T00_PCC
         GROUP BY TARJETA) A
      LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT FECHA_INFO,
                TARJETA,
                PCC,
                FECHA_COM,
                ADQUIRENTE,
                ESTADO
         FROM OPPF.T00_PCC)C ON(A.TARJETA = C.TARJETA
                                AND A.FECHA = C.FECHA_INFO)) C ON(TO_CHAR(C.TARJETA) = TO_CHAR(A.TARJETA))

   LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT MAX(SE_REVISO) SE_REVISO,
             NOMBRE_TH,
             TARJETA
      FROM OPPF.T00CASOSRESUELTOS
      GROUP BY TARJETA,
               NOMBRE_TH) B ON(SUBSTR(A.TARJETA,1,16) = SUBSTR(B.TARJETA,1,16)
                               AND A.FECHA_BONIFICACION = B.SE_REVISO)
   LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT MAX(FECHA_PAGO) FECHA_PAGO,
             TARJETA,
             REFERENCIA,
             COUNT(REFERENCIA) N,
             SUM(MONTO_LIQ) AS IMP_REC--, FECHA_TRXS

      FROM OPPF.T00_CC_RECUP
      GROUP BY TARJETA,
               REFERENCIA,
               FECHA_TRXS) D ON(TO_CHAR(D.TARJETA) = TO_CHAR(A.TARJETA)
                                AND D.REFERENCIA = A.REFERENCIA)
   LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT TARJETA,
             COUNT(TARJETA) TRANS,
             COUNT(REFERENCIA) NR,
             REFERENCIA,
             SUM(IMPORTE) IMP_REPRE
      FROM OPPF.T00_REPRESENTACIONES
      GROUP BY TARJETA,
               REFERENCIA) F ON(A.TARJETA = F.TARJETA
                                AND LPAD(TO_CHAR(A.REFERENCIA),23,'0') = LPAD(TO_CHAR(F.REFERENCIA),23,'0'))
   LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT MIN(FOLIO) FOLIO_EXP,
             TARJETA,
             FECHA_BONIFICACION
      FROM OPPF.T00EMISOR --WHERE FECHA_BONIFICACION BETWEEN '02/09/2015' AND '31/12/2015'

      GROUP BY FECHA_BONIFICACION,
               TARJETA
      ORDER BY FECHA_BONIFICACION,
               TARJETA,
               FOLIO_EXP) E ON(E.TARJETA = A.TARJETA
                               AND E.FECHA_BONIFICACION = A.FECHA_BONIFICACION)
   WHERE A.ENTRY_MODE IN ('   ',
                          '1',
                          '01',
                          '001',
                          '0',
                          '00',
                          '012',
                          '010',
                          '12',
                          '10',
                          '11',
                          '011'))
WHERE F_REEMBOLSO = '04/07/2017'

ORDER BY FOLIO,
         REFERENCIA
```

Comment: I'm sure you'll get answers explaining `DISTINCT` to you.  I just wanted to comment that in _most_ SQL queries, truly duplicated records are a sign of a poorly designed data model and/or a poorly written query.  Probably 9 times out of 10, when I have seen the `DISTINCT` keyword in beginner's code, it is a band-aid covering up a real problem.  You might want to ask yourself: why am I getting duplicate records in the first place?

Comment: yes, it is badly designed and the clients don't use the software quite well, both affects the data

Comment: Given how horrible the query is, @MatthewMcPeak is right: you're getting "duplicate" records because your query has poorly defined joins and filters. Obviously [your previous question on join complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47984589/146325) shows you are aware of this. But until you can explain the business logic which spawned this monster we're not going to be able to help you rewrite it.

Comment: Well in this question I just wanted to ask for how to solve duplicates without affecting the query and I don't think your comment helps in something

Comment: @arnoldssss If you just want the syntax for a band-aid, here it is: instead of `SELECT FOLIO_EXP, FOLIO, ...` use `SELECT DISTINCT FOLIO_EXP, FOLIO, ...` and you won't get any duplicate records in your query.  But, that will give distinct records considering all the columns in your result set.  If you just want distinct records for the four (4) columns you listed, you have to provide more information about your requirements.

Comment: what information could you need?

Answer (score 1):

In your case you don't want to get duplicated results so your best option to go is DISTINCT.

DISTINCT and GROUP BY have no difference at least by (Oracle-style):

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:32961403234212

Normaly GROUP BY is used for aggregate functions like MAX, MIN and others. Distinct is just to remove duplicate.

The SQL server detect if you have no aggregate functions and generates an execution plan as if you'd simply used "Distinct." So no big different realy.

So with DISTINCT you go with the right concept here.
Hope this helps.

Comment: ok, do you know where could I place distinct so make it works?